# Yii2 — Данные select, которые зависят от другого выбранного значения?

Tags: yii2

Всем привет!
У меня есть таблица RegionCity, в этой таблицы находятся области и города. Мне надо сделать так, когда пользователь 
выбирает выпадающем списке область, то в другом выпадающем списке должно подтягиваться города к этой области.
Как это реализовать без перезагрузки станицы.

в консоле получаю profile-city?id=2 - 404

Сама БД:
http://joxi.ru/12M5X8lhDPjq2J.png

view:

```
    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => '/user/ajax']);

    echo $form->field($model, 'region')->dropDownList($region,
        [
            'prompt' => 'Выбрать',
            'onchange' => '$.post("' . Url::to('profile-city?id=') . 
    '"+$(this).val(),
            function(data) {
                    $("select#city").html(data);
                });',
        ]
    );
    echo $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList($city,
        [
            'prompt' => 'Выбрать',
        ]
    );

    echo '<br>' . Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-
    success']);

    $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

controller:

```
    public function actionAjax()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $id = (int)Yii::$app->request->post('id');

        $region = RegionCity::find()
            ->where(['parent_id' => $id])
            ->count();

        $cities = RegionCity::find()
            ->where(['parent_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        if ($region > 0) {
            foreach ($cities as $city) {
                echo "<option value='" . $city->id . "'>" . $city->name_ru . "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function actionGetCities($id) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $cities = RegionCity::find()->select(['id', 'name_ru'])->where(['parent_id' => $id])->all();
        return ['success' => true, 'cities' => $cities];
    }

    return ['oh no' => 'you are not allowed :('];
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin();
    echo $form->field($model, 'region')->dropDownList($regionsArray, ['prompt' => 'Выберите область', 'id' => 'region-selector']);
    echo $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList([], ['prompt' => 'Выберите город', 'id' => 'city-selector']);
    echo Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
    ActiveForm::end();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#region-selector').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax('/your-controller/get-cities/' + this.value, {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#city-selector').empty();
                $.each(data.cities, function (key, val) {
                    $('#city-selector').append('<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name_ru+'</option>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: в консоле браузера ошибка
http://s019.radikal.ru/i620/1704/fe/ae36d2a2cb06.jpg

Comment: jquery поднял в head, теперь другая ошибка
http://s019.radikal.ru/i614/1704/ef/355533b2e644.jpg

Comment: @Uman в настройках UrlManager должно быть правило `'<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\d]+>' => '<_c>/<_a>'`